# Web 8.5 - How to implement and configure custom TCDL on Web site with RESTful Broker API?

Tags: content-delivery, broker, web8.5, tcdl

I intend to implement TCDL on Web 8.5
I'm using RESTful Broker API (Java).

I saw manual but I couldn't understand how to implement and configure TCDL.

[Creating custom TCDL tags](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dtcdl&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1505438406814&currentQuery=tcdl&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-448BF762-47F1-45BA-AF44-93E19C8E6645&docid=GUID-448BF762-47F1-45BA-AF44-93E19C8E6645&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-A87527C9-770C-49E5-A229-471A04ED7C3D.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false)

The manual describes to use `com.tridion.tcdl.TagRenderer` to create Java class, but there is no such class in RESTful Broker API.

Also the manual describes to edit  `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` and `tcdl-conf.xml`, but there is no such files in RESTful Broker API's classes directory.

"In process" API have `com.tridion.tcdl.TagRenderer` class, but I'm not sure whether it can be used in RESTful Broker API environment.

Does anyone know how to implement and configure TCDL on a Web site with RESTful Broker API?

Perhaps TCDL have to be installed in Content Service, not client Web site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementation requires the following steps:

1. To start to create your own custom TCDL tags jar using Maven + IntelliJ IDEA Java development tools to create a Java class that implements the interface `com.tridion.tcdl.TagRenderer`.
2. Dependent SDL jar files from `[Install-Media]\SDL Web 8.5\Content Delivery\roles\content\standalone\services\content-v2-service`

   - `cd_core-8.5.0-1011.jar`
   - `cd_dynamic-8.5.0-1014.jar`
   - `cd_linking-8.5.0-1014.jar`
   - `cd_tcdl-8.5.0-1014.jar`

     ```
     package com.sample.tcdl.tags;

     import com.tridion.tcdl.*;

     public class SampleImageRenderer implements TagRenderer
     {
         private String alt = "";
         private String target = "";

         private TransformContext context;

         public void setRequiredAlt(String alt)
         {
             this.alt = alt;
         }

         public void setTarget(String target)
         {
             this.target = target;
         }

         @Override
         public int doStartTag(Tag tag, StringBuffer content, TransformContext context, OutputDocument document) throws TCDLTransformerException {

             //ToDo
             return Tag.CONTINUE_TAG_EVALUATION;
         }

         @Override
         public String doEndTag(Tag tag, StringBuffer content, TransformContext context, OutputDocument document) throws TCDLTransformerException {
         }
             //ToDo
             return content.toString();
         }

         @Override
         public boolean requiresCodeBlock(TransformContext transformContext, OutputDocument outputDocument, Tag tag) 
         {
            return false;
         }
     }
     ```

     2. Update the Content Services.
        Copy the jar file eg. `sampleimage-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` into the `lib` folder of the Content Service this jar contains the Custom TCDL tag `control:image`
     3. In the file `cd_dynamic_conf.xml`, located in the `config` folder of the Content Service
        Add `<TagBundle Resource="SampleImageTagBundle.xml" />`; right before the closing tag `</TCDLEngine>`
        Note: `SampleImageTagBundle.xml` you can also include in the part of jar file, so that no need to copy it separately. This contains the tag definition of `control:image`

`tcdl-conf.xml` - you can find it in the `deployer-compined` or `deployer-worker` `config` folder of the micro services of installation media folder